# Launch Java class from another Java application

Tags: java

Is there a way to launch a java class (and pass it a classpath and libary path) from within a Java application with out using `Runtime.exec`?

I have seen:
[Launch a java application from another java application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2388634/launch-a-java-application-from-another-java-application)

but need to be able to pass a CLASSPATH and libary path.

I am trying to make a launcher that a user downloads, it downloads the required files and then launches them.

Thank You

Comment: Have you explored [Java Web Start](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/tech/index-jsp-136112.html)?

Comment: I want the user to download a file to anywhere on their machine, and the files to be downloaded to their home folder:
windows %appdata%\folderName
mac/linux ~/folderName

Comment: @adarshr  Exactly what I was thinking, but slightly [different link](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-web-start/info).  It includes links to a variety of helpful pages on JWS, including Oracle's own page on it.

Comment: *"I want.."*  Why?  What advantage does that provide to the end user?

Comment: Its a game that I am making a launcher, the game does not support mac and linux and I have created the launcher to pull download the game, download all the extra libs and files needed to make it work on linux/mac and play the game. exactly how the minecraft launcher works. it grabs the natives for lwjgl and hides everything in the user-home and the user just has to worry about the one tiny exe that they can keep anywhere on their system.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

https://stackoverflow.com/a/5575619/20394 should explain how to add to the library path and still use the same JVM.

To add to the classpath, create your own [`URLClassLoader`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URLClassLoader.html) and use that to [find](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html#loadClass%28java.lang.String%29) the class you want to load, then call its start method reflectively.

```
URLClassLoader classLoader = new URLClassLoader(
    urlsToDirectoriesAndJars, getClass().getClassLoader());
Class<?> myMainClass = classLoader.findClass("pkg.path.for.MainClass");
Method main = myMainClass.getMethod("main", String[].class);
main.invoke(null, new Object[] { new String[] { "args", "for", "main" } });
```

You'll need to handle some exceptions that are thrown by the reflective API but that's the gist of it.

If that class calls `System.exit`, then see [How to prevent calls to System.exit() from terminating the JVM?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5549720/how-to-prevent-calls-to-system-exit-from-terminating-the-jvm)